# ERROR 1064 when importing MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to import a MySQL database table using the following command in Terminal:

```
mysql -u root -p foo < ~/Desktop/users_table.sql
```

I am receiving the following error when I import:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for osx10.8
>   (i386) using readline 5.1 Copyright' at line 1

Here is what schema looks like and will execute when I import this database table -- this is at the top of my `users_table.sql`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `m0s1db28911_users`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `m0s1db28911_users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_login` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_pass` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_nicename` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_email` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_url` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_activation_key` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `display_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `spam` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `user_login_key` (`user_login`),
  KEY `user_nicename` (`user_nicename`),
  KEY `user_email` (`user_email`,`user_login`,`user_status`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6805601 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: working fine http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43f4c

Comment: **Obviously** `mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for osx10.8 (i386) using readline 5.1 Copyright` is the problem.

Comment: i guess this line `mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for osx10.8 (i386) using readline 5.1 Copyright` is just a comment so you forget to  comment it .

Comment: @echo_Me If We had a pound for every `ERROR 1064` here we would be rich

Comment: Does this mean I need to upgrade my MySQL version?

Comment: @davidstrachan rich for mysql , and rich for php , html , js u will be millioner :).

Comment: @Matt try to search inside your `users_table.sql` file for the line containing `mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for osx10.8 (i386) using readline 5.1 Copyright` and add it to the question including the surrounding lines

Comment: this query you provided works great , as rsanchez said look for that line and post it or maybe you forgot it uncommented.